# relations and extending entities symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to make an `entityB` that extends an `entityA`. In `entityA`, I have a relation many to many  with `entityC`. Is it possible to make it many to one in `entityB`?
Otherwise, could you provide me with other suggestions?

Comment: I wanted also to ask if the entityB could inherit the relation first of all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **single table inheritance** for instance. It has nothing to do with Symfony though , it is Doctrine related :

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: is it possible to inherit relation also? or it's impossible @mpm